# "Add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/."

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to make a CRUD on my form in my frontend folder, but all my controllers are inside the backend folder,

and react is telling me this

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../../backend/controllers/workoutController which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

I tried to import the controller of my backend in my form like this : `const { createWorkout, getWorkouts, getWorkout, deleteWorkout, updateWorkout } = require('../../../backend/controllers/workoutController');`

Since moving my controllers inside my frontend folder is a bad idea, i need to do a symlink but i have no idea how that work despite the doc

do i have to do `npm link` on my backend folder then `npm link` on my frontend folder ? do i need to import anything ?

Thanks

Comment: A symlink; that is not the same as npm link.

Comment: I don't quite understand your project structure; why would you want backend code on the front end?

Comment: @Dave Newton there is all the controllers for my CRUD on the controllers folder in my backend folder, but apparently i can't import things outside of the /src folder